# Extract GPS data using python and PIL is failing

Tags: python, gps, python-imaging-library

This code is from https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org, which is similar to others, which also fail in the same wayThis is the error code given

```
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS, GPSTAGS   
    filename="screenshot.jpg"
    
    def get_exif(image_file_path):
        exif_table = {}
        image = Image.open(image_file_path)
        info = image.getexif()
        for tag, value in info.items():
            decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
            exif_table[decoded] = value
            print (f'Tag={tag}, Value={value}, decoded= {decoded}')
        print (f'exif table is {exif_table}')
        gps_info = {}
        for key in exif_table['GPSInfo'].keys():
            decode = GPSTAGS.get(key,key)
            gps_info[decode] = exif_table['GPSInfo'][key]
        return gps_info
         
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        exif = get_exif(filename)
        print(exif)
```

The error message is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

for key in exif_table['GPSInfo'].keys():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'

I understand that the value for GPSInfo is itself a key into another part of the file which itself has keys and values regarding the latitude and longitude. In the case of this image file GPSInfo is 90. I assume that is a integer and that is what's causing the problem, but as the sample code appears in multiple places on the inter web, I can't see what the real problem is

I added some print lines right before the gps_info={} statement. This shows exactly what the line
`for key in exif_table['GPSInfo'].keys():`
is dealing with

Tag=34853, Value=90, decoded= GPSInfo
Tag=296, Value=2, decoded= ResolutionUnit
Tag=531, Value=1, decoded= YCbCrPositioning'Tag=282, Value=96.0, decoded= XResolution
Tag=283, Value=96.0, decoded= YResolution
exif table is {'GPSInfo': 90, 'ResolutionUnit': 2,
'YCbCrPositioning': 1, 'XResolution': 96.0,
'YResolution': 96.0}

The Tag 34853 correctly equates to GPSInfo. The value of GPSInfo in this file is 90.

I understand that at location 90 of the file, one would expect to find a string of values that represent key:value data for the GPS coordinates, hence the "for key in exif_table ['GPSInfo'].keys():"statement. I assume it fails because the value of exif_table["GPSInfo"] is 90 and seen as an integer, not a dictionary. It looks like a step is missing, but as its widely published code, I assume it must work and that it's me that has something wrong

Comment: Time to use the debugger - set a breakpoint at the line that causes the error and inspect what `exif_table` and  `exif_table['GPSInfo']` contain.

Comment: TDG - I added some results and values that shows what is going on

Comment: Am I to assume from the lack of answers that this code really doesn't work? I will try and contact the publisher and ask them to explain how it works

Answer (score 0):

Probably something is related to EXIF version or so.

I had the same problem, even though I didn't find a solution for pillow I did find a workaround thankfully to this article: https://medium.com/spatial-data-science/how-to-extract-gps-coordinates-from-images-in-python-e66e542af354

The workaround uses exif package instead of pillow, but if you need the last one, there should be a way to combine them.

**My code that didn't work:**

```
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ExifTags
from gmplot import gmplot
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import webbrowser
import os

filename = 'IMG_1874'
input = f'{filename}.jpg'
output = f'{filename}-location.html'

img = PIL.Image.open(input)

exif = {
    PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
    for k, v in img.getexif().items()
    if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
}

north = exif['GPSInfo'][2]
east = exif['GPSInfo'][4]

lat = ((north[0] * 60 + north[1]) * 60 + north[2]) / 3600
lon = ((east[0] * 60 + east[1]) * 60 + east[2]) / 3600

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(lat, lon, 12)
gmap.marker(lat, lon, 'red')
gmap.draw(output)

address = Nominatim(user_agent='GetLoc')
location = address.reverse(f'{lat}, {lon}')

print(location.address)

webbrowser.open(f'file:///{os.getcwd()}/{output}', new=1)
```

**The workaround using exif package:**

```
from exif import Image
from gmplot import gmplot
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import webbrowser
import os

def decimal_coords(coords, ref):
    decimal_degrees = coords[0] + coords[1] / 60 + coords[2] / 3600
    if ref == 'S' or ref == 'W':
        decimal_degrees = -decimal_degrees
    return decimal_degrees

filename = 'IMG_1874'
input = f'{filename}.jpg'
output = f'{filename}-location.html'

with open(input, 'rb') as src:
    img = Image(src)

lat = decimal_coords(img.gps_latitude, img.gps_latitude_ref)
lon = decimal_coords(img.gps_longitude, img.gps_longitude_ref)

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(lat, lon, 12)
gmap.marker(lat, lon, 'red')
gmap.draw(output)

address = Nominatim(user_agent='GetLoc')
location = address.reverse(f'{lat}, {lon}')

print(location.address)

webbrowser.open(f'file:///{os.getcwd()}/{output}', new=1)
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your interest, however the point was that the code, as published by reputable web site, doesnt and cannot work, and yet no one really cares...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to get only one value from a GPS position, but it came with more than an integer. Look my code behind to find the solution.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS, GPSTAGS

def get_exif(filename):
    exif_data = {}
    image = Image.open(filename)
    info = image._getexif()
    if info:
        for tag, value in info.items():
            decoded = TAGS.get(tag, tag)
            if decoded == "GPSInfo":
                gps_data = {}
                for gps_tag in value:
                    sub_decoded = GPSTAGS.get(gps_tag, gps_tag)
                    gps_data[sub_decoded] = value[gps_tag]
                exif_data[decoded] = gps_data
            else:
                exif_data[decoded] = value

    return exif_data    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exif = get_exif("image.jpg")
    print(exif)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading something similar and it can be worked around by using _getexit() instead of getexif()
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/5863